# How to show that $f(x) = 0$ is solvable by radicals over $K$ iif $f(x^n)=0$ is solvable by radicals over $K$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I found this property in one of the questions in here (perhaps written differently, but the result is the same).

I thought of computing the splitting fields of each polynomial and compare them, but I don't know what to do with that information afterwards.

Could anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f$ has roots $\alpha_1 ,...,\alpha_k $ then $f$ has splitting field $L=K(\alpha_1 ,...,\alpha_k )$. Letting $g=f(x^n)$ then if $g$ has roots $\beta_1 ,...\beta_k$ where $\beta_i ^n =\alpha_i .$ Using this you can compute the splitting field of $g$ over $K$.

Comment: The problem comes after I get this info. What can I do in order to prove either implications of the result?

Comment: $L(\beta_1) $ is contained in a radical extension since $\beta_1 ^n =\alpha_1 \in L $. Just argue this for each of the roots of $g$. (Here we are using that $f$ is solvable by radicals meaning that $L$ is contained in a radical extension of $K$.)

Comment: Oh, I see it better. Just to make sure, is the implication of '$g$ solvable by radicals $\Rightarrow$ $f$ solvable by radicals' trivial since the splitting field of $f$ is contained in the splitting field of $g$?

Comment: Yeah that's true